# Alternative Windows/bash command 'workon [insert virtualenv name]' for Mac Terminal

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I've seen you can activate virtualenv on Windows bash by typing 'workon [virtualenv name]' is there a similar command for the Mac Terminal which does the same thing?

I want to avoid the long way of activating the virtualenv, which is by going into the sub folder that contains 'bin' and then using 'source bin/activate'.

Comment: The `workon` command has nothing to do with Windows. It's provided by the [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which you could install on your Mac. You could also just write your own version of `workon` as a shell function that simply performs the `cd directory; . bin/activate`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+workon